# grouping images in a profile

Tags: php

I have a profile that shows profiles in a list. as shown in the image below.

[image]

**users** table

```
 id    |  email  |  full_name  |  job_title  | bio |  profile_photo
```

**images** table

```
 image_id  | id  | artist_img
```

**CODE**

```
<?php 

$db = dbconnect();
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT
 users.email,
 users.full_name,
 users.job_title,
 users.bio,
 users.profile_photo,
 images.id,
 images.artist_img
FROM users
INNER JOIN images ON users.id=images.id GROUP BY images.id');
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) != false) {

        $id = $row['id'];        
        $full_name = $row['full_name'];    
        $email = $row['email'];   
        $job_title = $row['job_title'];
        $bio = $row['bio'];
        $ProfilePhoto = $row['profile_photo'];
        $artist_img = $row['artist_img'];    


        if (isset($ProfilePhoto) && ! empty($ProfilePhoto)) {
            $image = "$ProfilePhoto";
        } else {
            $image = "avatar.jpg";
       }

   echo "<div class='container team-wrap'>
           <div class='row'>
             <div class='col-md-6'>
                <img class='img-responsive' src='artist/$image'>
               </div>
                 <div class=\"col-md-6\">
                    <strong>$full_name<br>$job_title</strong>
                      <br>
                      <p>$bio</p>
                      <a href='mailto:$email' class='btn btn-info'>Contact Me</a>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>

          <div class=\"container space team-wrap\">
           <div class=\"row\">
              <div class=\"col-lg-12\">
                    <div id=\"gallery-slider\" class=\"slider responsive\">
                      <div>";




                          echo"
                        <img src=\"gallery/$artist_img\" alt=\"\"></a>";  




                      echo "</div>
                    </div>
                  <hr>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>";
    }        
 ?>
```

**Problem area**

```
echo"<img src=\"gallery/$artist_img\" alt=\"\"></a>";
```

The issue I am having is that it repeats the profile for each image if the user has 5 images  it will add 5 profiles 1 for each img.

and does not show the other users profile at all. show how it shows up is look at the image for example its got 4 images under profile 1 and it shows there profile pic.. well it repats all that info for each image I want the pics that have the same id as the user to show up as a slider like below..

and it also refuses to show the other profiles of other users.

Comment: don't use `users, images` it is an old style use `any join` in your case use `users inner join images on users.id=images.id`. why writing these many echo just construct a string and echo it in the end of while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an array **example below**. the way your calling it now is as if it were just a variable so its only pulling 1.

```
$artist_img1=array();
$artist_img1 = $row['images']; 

$artist_img2=row2['id'];
echo "<img src=\"gallery/".$artist_img2."\" alt=\"\"></a>";
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are grouping the data in wrong fashion.

As your question describes you have multiple rows for a **user id** and you are trying to display these multiple results in a single row using the `GROUP BY`. So, This is not possible for database to group data like this because it does not know any relation between data and what is to do with multiple results.

However, you can use `JOIN` here as it is what you trying to do. Use the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `images` ON images.id = users.id
```

You should then process the result like this:

```
$users = [];
foreach($results as $row){
   if(isset($users[$row->userId]))
       $users[$row->userId][] = $row->imageUrl;

    else
        $users[$row->userId] = [$row->imageUrl];
}
```

`$users` is what you want.It should do the work.

Comment: using your formula the it does not show all users only 1 out of 3 and it recreateds hes profile 12 times for each image that is in his gallery

Comment: It is because your other users do not have any images related to them. So, those rows are not joining in the query.

Comment: that makes no sense, as shown in the image up top  the users images should display in a slider underneath there profile picture.. if they dont have any pictures in there profile yet it should still show the profile if they created one

Comment: Okay... I understand. Then, you should use left join instead of inner join. It will also include the remaining users to the result. I have updated the answer please check.

Comment: still same result it creates the profile of user 1 12 times and has a different image in the slider each time all of the images with users id should be in the slider

Comment: Because this is how sql works!! It returns results always in table. It does not have any concept of array as you want it to return. You have to either process the result in php or execute another query for users images to get your results in array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134865/discussion-between-codi-and-parantap-parashar).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
SELECT t.id,t.email,t.fullname,t2.image_id,t2.picture_name FROM table2 t LEFT JOIN table1 ON t2.id=t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Database entry must be like below tables.

**Table1 - users**

```
------------------------------------------
   id      |     email       |   full_name
------------------------------------------
    1      | test1@gmail.com |   test1
    2      | test2@gmail.com |   test2
    3      | test3@gmail.com |   test3
```

**Table2 - images**

```
------------------------------------------
   image id  |    id    |  picture_image  
------------------------------------------
    1        |     1    |   image1.jpg
    2        |     1    |   image2.jpg
    3        |     1    |   image3.jpg
    4        |     1    |   image4.jpg
    5        |     1    |   image5.jpg
    6        |     1    |   image6.jpg
    7        |     1    |   image7.jpg
    8        |     1    |   image1.jpg
    9        |     1    |   image2.jpg
    10       |     1    |   image3.jpg
    11       |     1    |   image4.jpg
    12       |     1    |   image5.jpg
```

Use below SQL Query to get images by UserID

```
SELECT * FROM users
INNER JOIN images
        ON (users.id = images.id)
WHERE (images.id = '1')
```

Above query will give you result of profile id 1.

Comment: i got that part, but what it is doing is it creates a duplicate  user profile for all images

Answer (score 0):

For thre query ou can use :

```
SELECT * FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `images` ON images.id = users.id
```

And you've to iterate all the pictures of users one by one, to distinct the profil picture (1st picture) from the others.

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();

$users = array();
foreach($results as $row){

    if (in_array($row['id'], $users)) {
        echo "Print profil picture";
    } else {
        array_push($users, $row['id']);     
        echo "Print the other pictures";                
    }    
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what your trying to do the you cannot echo information you don't have access to. your trying to echo info before there defined..

Comment: I've used the echo just to show how to apply the difference

Comment: I appreciate the help but cannot get any of it to work.. Im just gonna create another page to display the images.. by putting a link on users profile to view image..

Answer (score 0):

Change two lines you will get the result as expected

prepare('SELECT
    users.email,
    users.full_name,
    users.job_title,
    users.bio,
    users.profile_photo,
    images.id,
     GROUP_CONCAT(images.artist_img SEPARATOR '|') as artist_img
    FROM users
    INNER JOIN images ON users.id=images.id GROUP BY images.id');
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) != false) {

        $id = $row['id'];        
        $full_name = $row['full_name'];    
        $email = $row['email'];   
        $job_title = $row['job_title'];
        $bio = $row['bio'];
        $ProfilePhoto = $row['profile_photo'];
        // Spliting as array
        $artist_imgs  = explode("|",$row['artist_img']);    


        if (isset($ProfilePhoto) && ! empty($ProfilePhoto)) {
            $image = "$ProfilePhoto";
        } else {
            $image = "avatar.jpg";
       }

       echo "
           
             
                
               
                 
                    **$full_name
$job_title**

$bio

Contact Me
                
             
          

          
           
              
                    
                      ";



                          foreach($artist_imgs as $artist_img){
                          echo"";  
                           }



                      echo "

---

";
    }        
    ?>

Answer (score -1):

Try this as your SQL statement -

```
SELECT * FROM
    users 
    INNER JOIN images on users.id = images.id 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(image_id) as maxid, id from images GROUP BY id) as g 
       ON images.image_id = g.maxid
```

This should give you the desired results. Please note that it takes the most recent picture as the profile picture. If you want to use the first inserted image use MIN function instead of MAX.

Even though this works, I would still follow @parantap-parashar's answer as it is more elegant.

Comment: romeo the problem is  when the container echos out it echos for each image i need to have the images echo in the container not create a new container, only create a new container if its a different user

Comment: @Codi Okie. The above SQL will give you only one image record for every user even if there are multiple images per user. Isn't that the requirement ?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming from the previous responses you are getting the correct result set from your SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `images` ON images.id = users.id
```

i.e. a table of all users duplicating a row for each user based on the number of artists images they have or nulls in the image col if they have no images.

I think what you are missing is in your PHP.
You need to recognise a change in profile_ID to pump out your profile and then **in an inner loop** your images if there are any.

To be able to do this you need to store all the artist images first.

Therefore you set the first profile id, store up the images, then when you reach the next profile id you output everything before doing the same with the next one etc.

Note that the top `if` statement is skipped on the first pass.  Also note that the variables capturing profile details get overwritten for each duplicate row (sounds like 12 for your first profile in your test data) but as the data is the same each time this is not a problem.

You need to remember to output the last set of data when you exit the main loop.

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$profile=$result[0]['id']  // initialise
$imgs=array();             // inititalise
foreach($result AS $row)
{
    if($profile!=$row['id'])
    {
        $profile= $row['id'];

        echo "<div class='container team-wrap'>
              <div class='row'>
              <div class='col-md-6'>
              <img class='img-responsive' src='$image'>
              </div>
              <div class=\"col-md-6\">
                <strong>$full_name<br>$job_title</strong>
                  <br>
                  <p>$bio</p>
                  <a href='mailto:$email' class='btn btn-info'>Contact      Me</a>
               </div>
             </div>
             </div>";


       echo "<div class=\"container space team-wrap\">
             <div class=\"row\">
             <div class=\"col-lg-12\">
                <div id=\"gallery-slider\" class=\"slider responsive\">
                  <div>";


       foreach($imgs AS $img)
       {
            echo "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$img\">
                      <img src=\"$img\" alt=\"\"></a>";
       }
       $imgs=array(); // Empty out image array

       echo "     </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
              <hr>
           </div>";

    }


    $full_name = $row['full_name'];    
    $email = $row['email'];   
    $job_title = $row['job_title'];
    $bio = $row['bio'];
    $ProfilePhoto = $row['profile_photo']; 
    if (isset($ProfilePhoto) && ! empty($ProfilePhoto)) {
       $image = "$ProfilePhoto";
    } else {
       $image = "avatar.jpg";
    }           

    if($row['artist_img']!==NULL)
    {
       $imgs[]= $row['artist_img'];
    }


}
/* Catch last one */

$full_name = $row['full_name'];    
$email = $row['email'];   
$job_title = $row['job_title'];
$bio = $row['bio'];
$ProfilePhoto = $row['profile_photo']; 
if (isset($ProfilePhoto) && ! empty($ProfilePhoto)) {
     $image = "$ProfilePhoto";
} else {
     $image = "avatar.jpg";
}           

echo "<div class='container team-wrap'>
     <div class='row'>
     <div class='col-md-6'>
     <img class='img-responsive' src='$image'>
     </div>
     <div class=\"col-md-6\">
     <strong>$full_name<br>$job_title</strong>
      <br>
       <p>$bio</p>
     <a href='mailto:$email' class='btn btn-info'>Contact      Me</a>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>";


   echo "<div class=\"container space team-wrap\">
       <div class=\"row\">
        <div class=\"col-lg-12\">
         <div id=\"gallery-slider\" class=\"slider responsive\">
        <div>";
   foreach($imgs AS $img)
   {
       echo "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$img\">
             <img src=\"$img\" alt=\"\">
             </a>";
   }

   echo "     </div>
           </div>
           </div>
           </div>
          <hr>
       </div>";
```

Comment: ok not sure of what your trying to do here you have the same code 2 times i dont need to echo users full_name  2 times.. the only issue i had was will the image list that was to be displayed inside the 2nd container called gallery slider.

Comment: @codi  Yes, I know.  So to do that you need for each profile to have possibly Multiple images.  Your dataset is coming back with the same row for each image a profile has (just the image information is different) therefore to get what you want you have to handle the loop in the way I have described.  The second printout only occurs on the last loop and is needed because of the way the inner loop works.